# не пойму как преобразить в лямбда функцию

Tags: python, lambda

```
for i in ("abcdef")
    print(i)
    if i == 'c' or i == 'e':
        continue
    print(i)
```

каким образом выразить это все с помощью lambda ,помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Лямбды для таких вещей плохо подходят

Answer (score 2):

Прямо вот весь этот код в лямбду, а не какую-то его часть? Ну, например, так:

```py
f = lambda: [print(f'{i}\n' * (1 + (i not in 'ce')), end='') for i in "abcdef"]
f();
```

Вывод будет аналогичен выводу вашего кода.